# How to handover a custom rule for SonarQube to identify JavaScript constructors?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I was working on client side MVC framework like Angular JS. Be a part of project I have written some services to handle the restful client requests and responses by using Angular Api. Right now I am doing some code quality task by using SONAR Tool. But as per Angular JS Api service having one function we can call it is as a constructor with same name of service. For example

```
            angular.module('modulename').factory('ServiceName',[function(){
            function ServiceName() { }]);
```

Now issue with SonarQube. SonaQube reading this function name as a normal function name (serviceName) basing on some normal function hungarian notation rules but If I change this function name as a normal function name then functionality is not working as per Angular JS Api standards. So now I need to handover one custom rule to SONAR for omitting of checking these constructor name as normal function name. So can anyone please suggest me any ways to write custom rule for handling such kind of scenarios. Thanks in advance?